# Datatable How edit css of Collapse Button

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, datatable

I want to change on this example https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/customisation/buttonText.html
the css of the button colapse

i already search and try several things

Comment: Please put your code as a runnable snippet direct into your question. See https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code is equal to the example that i share with the link but if you insist what should i put ?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to add enough code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) to demonstrate what you are trying to do **in the question itself**?  As explained in [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428), questions asking for help with off-site code are off topic for Stack Overflow.  If you need help trimming your code down for the question, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can help.

Comment: Also, you wrote, *i already search and try several things*.  Might you please [edit] your question to share what you tried that did not work?  As it is, people may write answers with solutions you already tried; you're more likely to get useful help if people don't go off on wrong tangents.  See [ask].  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
div.dtsp-panesContainer button.dtsp-collapseAll{ your own css properties  }
```

Comment: Hi I was talking about inside the search options (Collapse All/ Show All)

Comment: div.dtsp-panesContainer button.dtsp-collapseAll try with this.

Comment: Similarly you can target other buttons as well.

Comment: works!!!!!!! ty very much, just a quick question can you explain how did you acquire the "ID" of the collapse button ?

Comment: I just inspected that button and I found everything there. A sort suggestion: You need to work on your debugging skills. PS: please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted. Thanks :)